# How do we connect our docker app to a locally running postgres?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm looking for a way to connect a docker container app so it can access Postgres database via https://postgresapp.com/

Was wondering if there are certain ports to open and what the yml file would look like to enable docker-compose to work with locally running postgres.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to put Postgres into a container or are you asking how to access an existing Postgres database from an application container?

Comment: @DJO3 The Latter. How do I access a DB from an application container where the DB is hosted locally on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make changes in postgres config files in host machine, especially

1) pg_hba.conf
2) postgres.conf

You can find above configuration in /var/lib/postgresql/[version]/ path

First check your docker0 bridge interface  it might be 172.17.0.0/16, if not change accordingly.

make changes in postgresql.conf path will be same as pg_hba.conf.

listenaddress to "*"

Then in pg_hba.conf add rule as

host all all 172.17.0.0/16 md5.

Then in docker application use host ip address to connect to postures running in host.

Answer (score -1):

There is no difference between accessing a database from inside a container or outside a container.

Let's say the Postgres database is running on `localhost`. If you want to connect to it from a small Python script, you can do so as follows, as found in the [Docs](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Using_psycopg2_with_PostgreSQL):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import psycopg2
import sys

def main():
    #Define our connection string
    conn_string = "host='localhost' dbname='my_database' user='postgres' password='secret'"

    # print the connection string we will use to connect
    print "Connecting to database\n ->%s" % (conn_string)

    # get a connection, if a connect cannot be made an exception will be raised here
    conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)

    # conn.cursor will return a cursor object, you can use this cursor to perform queries
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    print "Connected!\n"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In order for this script to run you need to install Python and psycopg2 on your local machine, probably in a virtual environment. Alternatively, you could put it in a container. Instead of installing everything manually, you would define a Dockerfile with your installation instructions. It would probably look something like this:

```
FROM python:latest
ADD python-script.py /opt/www/python-script.py
RUN pip install psycopg2
CMD ["python", "/opt/www/python-script.py"]
```

And if we build and run...

```
dave-mbp:Desktop dave$ ls -la
-rw-r--r--    1 dave  staff   135 Dec  8 19:05 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--    1 dave  staff    22 Dec  8 19:04 python-script.py

dave-mbp:Desktop dave$ docker build -t python-script .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  17.92kB
Step 1/4 : FROM python:latest
latest: Pulling from library/python
85b1f47fba49: Already exists 
ba6bd283713a: Pull complete 
817c8cd48a09: Pull complete 
47cc0ed96dc3: Pull complete 
4a36819a59dc: Pull complete 
db9a0221399f: Pull complete 
7a511a7689b6: Pull complete 
1223757f6914: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:db9d8546f3ff74e96702abe0a78a0e0454df6ea898de8f124feba81deea416d7
Status: Downloaded newer image for python:latest
 ---> 79e1dc9af1c1
Step 2/4 : ADD python-script.py /opt/www/python-script.py
 ---> 21f31c8803f7
Step 3/4 : RUN pip install psycopg2
 ---> Running in f280c82d74e7
Collecting psycopg2
  Downloading psycopg2-2.7.3.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.7MB)
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
Successfully installed psycopg2-2.7.3.2
 ---> bd38f911bb6a
Removing intermediate container f280c82d74e7
Step 4/4 : CMD python /opt/www/python-script.py
 ---> Running in 159b70861893
 ---> 4aa783be5c90
Removing intermediate container 159b70861893
Successfully built 4aa783be5c90
Successfully tagged python-script:latest

dave-mbp:Desktop dave$ docker run python-script
>> Connected!
```

Containers are largely a packaging solution. We'll be able to connect to an external database or API endpoint as if we were running everything from outside of a container.

There is one thing to keep in mind though...`localhost` may resolve to the virtual machine if you're using docker toolbox/virtualbox. In which case, you wouldn't connect to `localhost` unless you were running a bridged network connection in the VM. Otherwise, just specify the host IP instead of `localhost`.

Answer (score -1):

Postgres default port is `5432`.

Docker offers different [networking modes](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-host) to use. I can tell you how to achieve your goal using bridge mode (used by default).

There is always a bridge network that allows you access host machine. It is created by default and called `docker0`.

Run the following command in terminal `ip addr show docker0` to see your host ip available to all the containers you run.

Output on my machine:

```
developer@dlbra:~$ ip addr show docker0
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:b4:95:60:89 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Therefore you don't need any additional configuration in docker-compose.yml
You just have to configure your db host to the ip address you saw. In my case it would be `172.17.0.1`.

If your locally installed Postgres listens to a different port also specify that port in your application configuration.